# Formal systems in which $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}(x \neq 0 \rightarrow x^{-1} \neq 0)$ is true, but the contrapositive is disallowed.

Tags: logic, reference-request, foundations, type-theory, formal-systems

> **Question.** Are there any formal systems out there for which $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}(x \neq 0 \rightarrow x^{-1} \neq 0)$$
>
> is true, but the contrapositive
>
> $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}(x^{-1} = 0 \rightarrow x = 0)$$
>
> is "ill-formed" or "ill-typed" (or whatever)?

*Motivation 0.* This seems to accord well with mathematical practice; in the sense that if you asked a typical mathematician whether or not the first statement was true, they'd probably say 'yes', but if you asked them whether the second statement was true, they'd probably start feeling uncomfortable, and probably suggest adjoining an $x \neq 0$ premise.

*Motivation 1.* I'm interested in whether there's formal systems out there that provide convenient ways of reasoning about functions whose domain isn't exactly what you wish it were.

Also, please, no answers of the form "this makes no sense because..." I think that, as a general rule, jumping to these kinds of conclusions too quickly is stifling and just an all-round bad idea.

Comment: I think formally, the consequent should be well-formed independently of the antecedent. In this sense the first is as ill formed as the second. Though I agree that intuitively the first statement seems fine, whereas the second is off.

Comment: @Servaes, that's exactly what I want to get away from.

Comment: Usually this issue is circumvented by not having the inverse element as part of the formal language, i.e., one would write $\forall x((\exists y(xy=1)\to \forall y(xy=1\to y\neq 0)))$.

Comment: @GitGud, I agree. But from a practical perspective, you know, not being able to write $\frac{x}{y}$ is kind of stifling.

Comment: @goblin I've asked the exact same question to my lecturer back in the day, he basically told me that in a formal language one simply doesn´t do that. It's not like formal languages are practical anyway...

Comment: @GitGud, it amazes me how stuck people are. They say "you don't do that" (implicitly, that we're not allowed to do it) when what they really mean is "I've never seen it done." Its pretty sad, really. I also don't agree with the statement that "formal languages are impractical." More like the *current* ones aren't practical - a very different statement.

Comment: @goblin Wrong choice of words, perhaps. How much do you have to win by making this work, though?

Comment: @GitGud, well - since I'm interested in practical computer formalizations of math - rather a lot...

Comment: @goblin Honestly, I am not a logician but it just seems really inconvenient to me to do this. For starters, in the language of fields $(-)^{-1}$ is not a function symbol (because $0^{-1}$ is not a term). I am not sure how to treat partial functions from a model theory perspective - although, perhaps we are all stuck on the notion of a field, even though there is posssibly a much more useful notion: that of a meadow / von Neumann regular Ring, which is *actually* algebraic. In a meadow, $0^{-1} = 0$, so the problem you describe disappears.

Comment: @goblin How does it matter exactly? Computational-efficiency wise? If so, does it really make that big a difference? I really don't know. Genuinely curious here.

Comment: @GitGud, not 100% sure - mainly just curious as to whether this is possible - but from a type-theoretic perspective, $x:\mathbb{R}, x \neq 0 \vdash x^{-1} \neq 0$ is fine. And I would like to get rid of $\vdash$, so $(\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \neq 0)(x^{-1} \neq 0)$ looks pretty reasonable. I think it would be nice to go that final step and get $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}(x \neq 0 \rightarrow x^{-1} \neq 0)$ as well-formed and true.

Comment: @StefanPerko, I agree that if you're just interested in fields, from e.g. a theoretical standpoint, then this would be inconvenient. But I'm not. The sentences I wrote aren't sentences in the language of fields btw, since it doesn't have an $\mathbb{R}$ symbol. And moving to meadows is too clever by half, at least for my purposes. The question I'm interested in is whether there's formal systems out there that provide convenient ways of reasoning about functions whose domain isn't exactly what you wish it was; so moving to fields just dodges the question.

Comment: @StefanPerko, I've added this motivation to the question to clear up any confusion.

Comment: I'm not convinced that what makes you uncomfortable about the second statement has anything to do with functions.  Wouldn't you feel the same about, say, "$x \neq 0 \rightarrow 2 > 1$" and its contrapositive, "$2 \le 1 \rightarrow x = 0$"?  The problem isn't that the premise is "ill-formed", just that it's always false, right?

Comment: I'd say that both those sentences are true. The first because $0 \neq 0$ is false (and thus truly implies anything), and the second because $0 = 0$ is true (and thus truly implied by anything). The "converses" are more weird. I'd say that $0^{-1} \neq 0 \rightarrow 0\neq 0$ is false (and not assertable), while $0=0 \rightarrow  0^{-1} = 0$ is silly (which in my system is assertable). Since nonzero $x$ are ok, the "converse" of your first statement should be false, but the second assertable (yet silly). Implication should make Heyting algebra and "not" should be an order reversing involution.

Comment: @mjqxxxx : the difference is that, for some, "implied by anything" does not include "implied by undefined terms". So $(1 = 4) \to (0 = 0)$ would be fine, but $(4/0 = 1) \to (0 = 0 )$ is not. One way to see where this perspective might come from: if $\to$ is a function of truth values, then both sides need to have a well-defined truth value before the function can be applied. $4/0 = 1$ is not false, from that perspective - it has no truth value at all.

Answer (score 1):

I addressed this in a comment on some SE answer I can no longer find. One way is to adopt guarded conditionals like the ternary operator in programming language, which allows us to enforce syntactic type-checking restrictions. In general one would probably like to have at least:
$\def\imp{\rightarrow}$
$\def\cand{\mathbin{?\land}}$
$\def\cimp{\mathbin{?{\rightarrow}}}$
$\def\then{\mathbin{?}}$

> $A \cand B = ( A \then B : \bot )$.
>
> $A \cimp B = ( A \then B : \top )$.

Then in the context where $x$ is real, "$x \ne 0 \cimp x^{-1} \ne 0$" is syntactically valid and true, because "$x^{-1}$" is valid in the subcontext where $x \ne 0$. In contrast "$x^{-1} = 0 \imp x = 0$" is syntactically invalid and hence meaningless since $^{-1}$ is a function that only accepts nonzero reals.

Division by zero is just one example, but it is not a very good one because some people would just force $0^{-1} = 0$ in the formal system so that they can get away with not solving the problem. However, there are many other instances of such things which are not so easily solved. For example, one instance of Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem is:
$\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}$
$\def\rr{\mathbb{R}}$

> Given any function $f : \nn \to [0,1]$, there is some $c \in [0,1]$ such that, for any $k \in \nn$, there is some $n \in \nn$ such that $f(n) \in [c-\frac1k,c+\frac1k]$.

But "$f(n)$" is syntactically valid only if $f$ is a function! We have two options:

1. Use guarded conditionals in the same way as for the real inverse, namely as in the sentence "$\forall f\ ( f \in Func(\nn,[0,1]) \cimp \cdots )$".
2. Allow restricted quantifiers such as "$\forall f \in Func(\nn,[0,1])$" and therefore we can allow the use of $f$ under the scope of quantification as a function.

The division example could be stated using the second option as in "$\forall x \in \rr_{\ne 0} ( x^{-1} \ne 0 )$", but to define "$\rr_{\ne 0}$" probably still needs the first option as in "$\{ r : r \in \rr \cand r \ne 0 \}$". The 'converse' that is as you say ill-formed would indeed be syntactically invalid, because "$\{ r : r \in \rr \cand r^{-1} \ne 0 \}$" is invalid.

Anyway I prefer having both options. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about **existing** computer proof assistants to tell you whether any of them support this. Probably any system that has a strict type system will support this, but potentially not allow you to do mathematics as freely as you might want. (Coq does not allow subtyping. Mizar does but its types are only in the sense of abbreviation power.)

Comment: In Coq, [these two statements are provable](https://gist.github.com/gallais/8091c47f6bcc7486b5f50356169b3761).

Comment: @gallais: Thanks for that. As I said, I don't know much about Coq, but I had read that there are two incompatible definitions of reals that are in common use in Coq, and my point was about the general situation, not just about reals.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there are no very well-known systems that handle this sort of thing. "Real" natural-language mathematics is done in a kind of free logic where particular terms (such as $0^{-1}$ and $0/0$) are undefined.

Ordinary first-order logic does not handle undefined terms at all. There are "[free logics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/)" which do allow for undefined terms, but they do not match all the subtleties of natural-language mathematics. In particular, both of the formulas in the question are well-formed in free logics - these logics do not try to modify *which* formulas are well-formed, they only try to handle reasoning with formulas that may involve undefined terms.

Part of the challenge is that natural-language mathematics does not separate the syntax from meaning in the same way that formal systems do. Formal logic tends to begin by defining a class of uninterpreted formulas, and then assigning them a meaning. Mathematicians tend to treat a natural-language statement as mathematical (that is, as a "proposition") exactly *when* it has an unambiguous meaning.  So the directions are reversed.

Of course, there is a standard way to handle these things in first-order logic, which is replace all function symbols that might be interpreted as partial functions with relation symbols, and then rewrite formulas accordingly. Then the only terms are constants and variables, so the issue of undefined terms goes away. A prototype of this is seen, for example, in the usual language for fields, which is $(+, \times, 0, 1)$ and not $(+, \times, {}^{-1}, 0, 1)$, and $y = x^{-1}$ is treated as a binary relation $I(x,y) \equiv xy = 1$.  So $(\forall x)(x \not = 0 \to x^{-1} \not = 0)$ becomes either
$$
(\forall x)(x \not = 0 \to (\forall y)[I(x,y) \to y \not = 0])
$$
or
$$
(\forall x)(x \not = 0 \to (\exists y)[I(x,y) \land y \not = 0])
$$
which are equivalent over the axioms for a field.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, because if you replace partial functions with relation symbols and use syntactic rewriting then you cannot have those same functions being objects in the domain, one consequence being that you cannot quantify over functions. If you take the example from my answer, you won't be able to quantify over functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $[0,1]$, in the same way that ZFC can. The problem with ZFC is that it faces the incongruity stated in the asker's question, since the function application syntax is ill-formed unless you know it is a function.

Comment: One hack is to consider "$f(x)$" to mean "$\{ z : \langle x,y \rangle \in f \land z \in y \}$", so that it works regardless of whether $f$ is a function, but that doesn't at all correspond to what people think when they write down a mathematical statement about functions, which is the issue here.